# shapes of lists and arrays and how to use them in input and output

Tags: python, reshape, shapes

I am trying to read and write data to a file and plot it afterwards. A MWE could be like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aa = 0.378
bb = 0.673
name = 'test.txt'

with open(name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('{},{}'.format(aa, bb))

cc = np.genfromtxt(name, delimiter=',')
plt.plot(cc[:,0], cc[:,1])
```

But I always get the error:

```
IndexError: too many Indices for array
```

I do not understand why. How would I have to rear or write respectively the data into the file so that it works?

Even if I reshape the array cc, it does not work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aa = 0.378
bb = 0.673
name = 'test.txt'

with open(name, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('{},{}'.format(aa, bb))

cc = np.genfromtxt(name, delimiter=',')
np.reshape(cc,(1,2))
print(np.shape(cc))
plt.plot(cc[:,0], cc[:,1])
```

The printed shape is (2,). I don't get this because if I initialize i.e. an array like
     aa = np.ones((1,2))
the shape is the desired shape (1,2) and I can also use aa[:,0] and aa[:,1] without error.

Comment: write some other lines in your file and it will work.

Comment: I found out the same thing. But why doesn't it work with only one line?

Comment: implementation choice & numpy philosophy . it keeps the minimum necessary dimensions.

Comment: But if I tell it to have the dimension (1,2), how come the actual dimension is (2,)?